# MSSQL select nearest match (id) of specified condition

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table filled with some words of different length.

```
ID | WORD  | LENGTH  
1  | able  |   4
2  | acid  |   4
3  | about |   5
.....
```

method in C# is generating random number and I want to get word with nearest match of length and ID. Recently I am using this query

```
select top 1 word from vocabulary where length = 4 and id <= 3;
```

problem is that this way it always returns first occurrence of word with 4 letters. That's not what I need.

I can't use this:

```
select top 1 word from vocabulary where length = 4 and id <= 3;
```

because when the random number is close to the last id in the table, it could happen that there will be no other word with requested length. (e.g.

```
 select top 1 word from vocabulary where length = 4 and id >= 2;
```

would not be able to find match.

Is there a way how to select 1 value that has nearest match in the requested direction? <= or >=

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it involves subtraction and the abs function, but perhaps easier to understand what you mean if you give a little more data + a input query + what you expect to get back..

Comment: I am creating a password generator that will use some random words, so when C# generates random number, it will be taken as "starting point" (ID) for SQL query. (something like: start searching from this ID in this (<;>) direction and look for word with this length.) Direction is determined by value of that random number. Basically, what is higher than half of the records is < and if that random number is lower, direction is >. (to ensure there is always enough word to select from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @vocabulary table (ID int, Word varchar(max), LENGTH int)
insert into @vocabulary(ID,Word,LENGTH)values(1,'able',4),(2,'acid',4),(3,'about',5)
declare @random int = rand() * 10
select @random
select top 1 word from @vocabulary where LENGTH = 4 order by ABS(ID - @random)
```

Result is the neareast id from random number

Comment: PERFECT!!!! Thanks! (my reputation is still too low to show the votes, sorry :-) ) Works like a charm.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, I am pretty much new here. :-) I can only hope that some day I'll be good enough to help others just like you helped me. Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you need the `select @random`?

Comment: It's just for exemple like rand() * 10, the select is there for verify that the result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's crucial to retrieve the row based on an *externally* generated random number, but if you just want a random word of given length, you could do something like this...

Setup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DICTIONARY;

CREATE TABLE DICTIONARY (

    ID int,
    WORD nvarchar(255),
    LENGTH AS LEN(WORD),

    CONSTRAINT DICTIONARY_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),

);

CREATE INDEX DICTIONARY_I1 ON DICTIONARY (LENGTH) INCLUDE (WORD);

INSERT INTO DICTIONARY (ID, WORD) VALUES
    (1, 'able'),
    (2, 'acid'),
    (3, 'about'),
    (4, 'boss'),
    (5, 'brain'),
    (6, 'child'),
    (7, 'computer'),
    (8, 'hint'),
    (9, 'human'),
    (10, 'ichthyosaur'),
    (11, 'mother'),
    (12, 'otorhinolaryngologist');
```

Query for getting a random row of given length (4 in this example):

```
DECLARE @length int = 4;

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM DICTIONARY WHERE LENGTH = @length ORDER BY NEWID();
```

The query plan is nice, which may be important for a large table and/or frequent querying:

[image: Query Plan]